# Connect to Active directory to create a dynamic organizational chart

Tags: dynamic, active-directory, sharepoint-2013, organizational-chart

I have a few questions regarding how to connect to Active Directory to create a dynamic organizational chart. First I want to say that this topic is new to me and I don't have any background in dealing with AD or asp.NET, so I want to know if this scenario is possible to implement:

I want to create an organizational chart in a webpage that is connected to AD so that it can dynamically reflects the changes in employees positions and departments. I was thinking about using Sharepoint 2013 or an asp.NET page.

If the answer is yes, can you please estimate the time required to learn and then implement something like that? Because I only have 2 weeks for the project.

Thank you in advance, if you have any suggestions or know applications that does this please feel free to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SharePoint has the inbuilt ability to create an organisational chart from AD. There is a web part called OrgChart and you can add it to any page in your SharePoint site you like.

This is of course assuming that you have properly configured the user profile service and that the manager property has been set. User Profile Service configuration is notoriously problematic, but if you've already got this set up, it will be a 5 minute job.

See this blog for further information on adding OrgChart step by step> https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-an-org-chart-in-sharepoint/

Without User Profile Service configured, it could take a good couple of days (worst case - you might be lucky to get it sorted first time!). Here is a step by step on setting this up > https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/setup-and-start-the-sharepoint-2013-user-profile-service/

Good luck!